# necessary and sufficient conditions for a linear operator $T$ to be of a certain form

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=\mathbb{C}$ as a *real* inner product space with the inner product defined by $(\alpha | \beta)=Re(\alpha\overline{\beta})$. For each $\gamma \in V$, let $M_{\gamma}$ be the linear operator on $V$ defined by $M_{\gamma} (\alpha)=\gamma \alpha$. Find necessary and sufficient conditions for a linear operator $T$ to be an $M_{\gamma}$.

This is a problem in section 8.4 of Linear Algebra, Hoffman 2nd ed.

The only necessary condition that I have found is that if $T$ is an $M_{\gamma}$ then $det T \geq 0$ , because $det T= a^2+b^2$ where $\gamma = a + ib$.

And a sufficient condition that comes to my mind, is that any rotation operator is an $M_{\gamma}$, with $\gamma=e^{i\theta}$ and $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$

Are there any other necessary and sufficient conditions ?

(In general, when one is asked to list necessary/sufficient conditions of a statement, it is not clear to me how many conditions are expected...is there a general advice for such problems? Of course the more conditions the better ....)